# How disable sorting on click on column title but allow for click on arrow in jQuery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am rendering a table thanks to jQuery datatable plugin .

When you allow sorting on a column , column is sorted if you click on title text or on arrow just near:

[image]

Do you know how to disable sorting for click on text but let sorting for click on arrows?

Comment: You need to add something like this: `"bSortable": false,` If you share the code you're using to render the table, I can show you exactly where it goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solve it this way (found the solution here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/27035/how-to-disable-sorting-click-event-on-table-header-children):

If you supose the checkbox has the ID #chkbx, this code should work:

```
$('#chkbx').click(function(event){

  //Your code here

  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

With the event.stopPropagation() prevent the sorting of the column.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
      "aoColumnDefs": [
          { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1 ] }
       ]
});
```

1 is your column number (remember the first column is actually 0).

Comment: thank but i don't want to disable sorting, just disable sorting when i click on title text